# Add checkbox 'add comment' to close votes

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

When voting to close questions because they are possible dupes there's a comment appearing automatically linking to the question that could answer the possible dupe. I think that's helpful.

I sometimes tend to comment when I vote to close a question because it doesn't include a code sample or is too broad, but most of the time I don't because it's more work than value for some questions. I'm quite sure (especially new users) never read or recognize that their questions are bad because the little `close(2)` isn't really annoying or draws attention until the question is closed.

[image]

Wouldn't it be good to have a checkbox next to the `close` Button where we can choose to include a comment explaining the close vote like its explained to the voter.

[image]

Same text, just as comment.

Comment: [Viewing close votes is a 250 rep privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes), so new users can't even see them accumulating.

Comment: Oh thanks, didn't know that @apaul34208. Where's the sense behind hiding this from the OP?

Comment: I honestly don't know, I would guess that it reduces server requests, or perhaps just reduces noise from new users. It seems like a bad policy though, while I support this change, it may be better to start with exposing close votes at a lower threshold.

Comment: I think the reason is that a) a single vote might just be wrong and thus confusing b) even if not wrong it's still confusing for the new ones. c) avoiding overloading them with data d) generally too much drama.

Comment: I agree with b), but a) would also mean that a single vote for a duplicate shouldn't be a comment. @Deduplicator.

Comment: Well, the possible duplicate isn't just a comment, it's a full-fledged big banner, with explanation, link(s), and a prompt for action, something like: Possible duplicate found (up to four duplicates here), is it right than [accept], if not \[edit\] to clarify your question....

Comment: That's only because of your gold badge @Deduplicator. When someone without it votes to close a question as duplicate it's a single line comment with a link only.

Comment: Nono, that's what happens since maybe half a year already. It begins with the first vote, and ends when dismissed by doing either action or by closing (a mod or appropriate gold-badger goes directly to closed.Of course, anyone but OP can only see the closed-banner or the comment.

Comment: Ok, didn't know that. @Deduplicator

Comment: Looks like you inspired someone on [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261409/can-we-have-an-option-to-post-a-selected-close-reason-as-a-comment)

Comment: @rene - I guess great minds think alike as I was not aware of the MSO post.

Comment: I'm totally in for the great minds. @PM77-1

Comment: Let the voting begin to determine how much SO wants this and how much the rest of the SE network-sites like this ;)